# Restricted Facebook Page Details over Graph API using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook's PHP SDK to get the number of likes for a fan page. This works fine for most pages, but some pages are returning false because they have age restrictions. Using the PHP SDK, how do I get the number of likes for an age restricted fan page over the graph API?

I'm currently not using an access token to read the pages. Would an app access token work? And if so how do I use an app access token with the PHP SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricted pages can be read using the graph api but it requires a user's access token. I had tried it with an app access token which does not work.

The relevant documentation can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Answer (score 0):

You should to use Page access token. To get list of your pages with access tokens, use **me/accounts** method of the Graph API.